# How can you determine if a user has Facebook liked your page or not?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

One of my sites pages has a FB like button. Once the user likes the our FB page I don't want to keep showing the Like Us box.

Is there a way to know if a user has clicked liked so you can prevent it from reappearing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

fql seems to be a solution but i wasn't able to make it work so far.

http://unbound-media.com/facebook/how-to-tell-if-a-facebook-user-likes-your-facebook-application/