# Is there a way to know if a user has liked an object on facebook?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to know if a user has liked an object on facebook, given that the user has given my app permission and I have the correct access tokens ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750012/facebook-check-if-user-liked-the-page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397724/how-to-check-if-user-has-already-liked-the-facebook-page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486829/how-can-you-determine-if-a-user-has-facebook-liked-your-page-or-not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607854/facebook-detect-if-user-has-liked-your-page

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook how to check if user has liked page and show content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246449/facebook-how-to-check-if-user-has-liked-page-and-show-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to me that it is what are you asking for ...
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

Comment: Is there a way to do it via the graph api?? Something like a get request with the access token or something??

Comment: of course ... FB states you have to consider fql as part of Graph api read here about ... https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/579/

Answer (score 0):

For people who come across this page and want a more specific answer, I use the following FQL query via the js sdk in order to find out if a specific user has liked a specific object. If they have, it will return an array with their id. If they haven't, it will return an empty array:

```
        FB.api({
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'select user_id from like where user_id=' + UserIDVar + ' and object_id=' + ActionIDVar,
            return_ssl_resources: 1
        }, function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
```